# Camel transactional JMS Weblogic: big number of "consumers total" is normal?

Tags: java, transactions, jms, weblogic, apache-camel

I use Apache Camel 2.10.0 running in WebLogic 10.3.5
The following route is defined:

```
from("wmq:jms/myqueue").to( some logic goes here )
```

If I make it transactional

```
from("wmq:jms/myqueue?transacted=true").to( some logic goes here )
```

it works as expected but the number of "total consumers" (monitored in WebLogic console) is increased every second.
For example:

At server start we have

- Consumers Current = 1
- Consumers High = 1
- Consumers Total = 1
- Messages High = 0

5 min later (no messages sent)

- Consumers Current = 1
- Consumers High = 1
- Consumers Total = 1668
- Messages High = 0

Does it mean memory leak? Could it be a problem for production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look on the camel-jms documentation page

- http://camel.apache.org/jms

And pay attention to using transaction and the impact on performance and about what the cacheLevel option can be set to.

In your use case, when using transacted=true, then the cache level is by default none, which means a new consumer is created per poll. Setting the cache level to consumer will reuse the consumer and you should only have a consumers total of 1, just like without caching.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much, Claus. 
You right, I missed this part of the documentation. Now it works perfectly